# Como navegar nas tabs ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Olá! Criei as tabs no meu html do ionic e quero quando clicar abra a página destino, aparece as tabs certinho porém ao clicar só muda os icones para ativo e não seta a página, meu código esta assim
no home.html

```
<ion-footer>
 <ion-toolbar>
   <ion-tabs>
      <ion-tab [root]="homeRoot" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="information-
        circle"></ion-tab>      
      <ion-tab [root]="listroot" tabTitle="Chat" tabIcon="information-
        circle"></ion-tab>  
   </ion-tabs> 
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

código no home.ts

```
 export class HomePage {

 homeRoot = ChatPage
 listroot = ListPage

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {} }
```

Comment: Faça um teste, coloque a atribuição da sua page como string. Ex: `homeRoot = 'ChatPage';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o nome para a tab

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs>

@ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

this.tabRef.select(1); //1 é o índice da tab
```